# Spring Boot Shows OS-Specific Behavior with @ConditionalOnMissingBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I'm currently facing an issue with my Spring Boot application that exhibits OS-specific behavior concerning bean registration, specifically when running the application as a packaged JAR on MacOS(arm silicon).

Situation:
My application defines a bean in two configuration classes, DefaultConfig and LocalConfig, with the latter being activated under the "local" profile. Both configurations attempt to define a bean of type AppServiceResolver, but only LocalConfig should do so when the "local" profile is active. **This setup works flawlessly when running through the IDE on both Windows and MacOS**, and even when executed as a JAR file on Windows. The issue arises exclusively when running the JAR on macOS, leading to a BeanDefinitionOverrideException.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'appServiceResolver', defined in class path resource [com/example/project/config/LocalConfig.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [com/example/project/config/DefaultConfig.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

DefaultConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class DefaultConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(AppServiceResolver.class)
    AppServiceResolver appServiceResolver() {
        return new DefaultServiceResolver();
    }

    // Additional bean definitions...
}
```

LocalConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@Profile("local")
public class LocalConfig {

    @Bean
    AppServiceResolver appServiceResolver(){
        return new LocalServiceResolver();
    }

    // Additional bean definitions under "local" profile...
}
```

For build process I use this command.

```
./gradlew clean bootJar
```

**Environment Details:**

- Spring Boot version: 3.0.5
- Java version: 17.0.10

Despite thorough investigation and ensuring all configurations and profiles are correctly set up, I've been unable to determine why my Spring Boot application behaves differently when run as a packaged JAR on macOS with ARM silicon. The application runs flawlessly within the IDE on both Windows and macOS, and as a JAR on Windows, but not when executed as a JAR on macOS, leading to a BeanDefinitionOverrideException.

I understand that renaming the conflicting bean method could resolve the issue, but I'm seeking a solution that doesn't involve changing the Java source code, considering it runs fine in the IDE. This situation has led me to wonder if the behavior could be related to running on MacOS's ARM architecture.

Could this issue be related to the macOS ARM architecture, or is there a way to resolve this bean registration conflict without modifying the source code?

Thank you for any insights or suggestions you might have.

Comment: the class order could be different...try to put there `@Order` and order them like local first and then default.

Comment: @bilak Ah, Right. I did see a difference in class loading order with -verbose:class, but I wasn't sure if that impacts bean definition order.  Class loading order indeed varies  across OSs. I'll try using Order annotation to see if it helps. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Either `@Order` or `@ConfigureBefore` || `@ConfigureAfter` should do the trick